# Ускорение работы скрипта, тессеракт, считывание, python

Tags: python

Пишу кое-что для покера, в качестве помощи для себя. Программирование изучаю два месяца и сугубо для покера, на читабельность или критические ошибки не ругаемся. Код собирал по кусочкам с интернета, так что даже банально использование PIL и CV2 в одном месте глупо, знаю это.
Проблема вот в чем, нужно ежесекундное считывание покерного стола, а то и вовсе быстрее в идеале, но никак не могу придумать как это сделать.
Опишу код - три функции, "скрин", "клонирование скрина", "тессеракт". "клонирование скрина" - выполняет клонирование, предположим что "9" это скрин, он превращает его в "99999". Тессеракт не считывает один символ, покра немере в моих руках.
Что пробовал: склеивать все скрины в ряд для считывание(их в примере только два, по факту от 2 до 7) - не получилось, так как считывание происходит не идеально и выдается например на карте "10" IU, а может и |0 и парсить слишком затруднительно да и сильно считывание отличается от посимвольного в плане выдачи результата(посимвольно качественнее), ерунду порой выдает, если вместе все скрины склеить. Пробовал уменьшать количество клонирований до 2,3,4, но стабильный результат всегда только на 5 клонированиях(проверял в реальном времени во время игры). Пробовал чисто ради интереса не в ряд, а в столбик, тоже ерунду делает. Просто разовый вызов тессеракта будет быстрее(если все склеить), чем вызов его 7 раз(если по отдельности 7 разных фрагментов). Так же в коде используется увеличение картинки в 5 раз, так как мелкие он не считывает, таковы особенности работы с этой библиотекой, раз на раз не приходиться.
Для понимания - время исполнения обычно колеблется от 2 до 4 секунд, это слишком долго, отсюда вопрос или просьба, **подскажите/помогите примером/вбросьте мысль/укажите на ошибки - как можно ускорить работу кода? **

```
from PIL import Image
import pytesseract
import cv2
import pyautogui

# Координаты считывания для карманных карт
pocket_card_left = 302
pocket_card_right = 346
pocket_card_top = 322
pocket_card_width = 18
pocket_card_height = 21
# Переменные с именами скриншотов
img_pocket_card1 = 'img_pocket_card1.png'
img_pocket_card2 = 'img_pocket_card2.png'

def img_increase(img,how):
       # Клонирует картинку в ряд на заданное количество, возвращает имя новой картинки.
       img = Image.open(img, 'r') 
       img_w, img_h = img.size 
       image = Image.new("RGB", ((img_w*how), (img_h)) )
       i = 0
       w = 0
       while i < how:
           image.paste(img, (w, 0))
           w = w + img_w
           i = i + 1
       name_img = 'tmp_zoom.png'
       image.save(name_img)
       
       return name_img

def read_card(img):
   # Ковертирует картинку в текст
   image = cv2.imread(img)
   image = cv2.resize(image, None, fx=5, fy=5)
   gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
   gray = cv2.threshold(gray, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY | cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1]
   custom_config = r'-l eng --psm 6'
   text = pytesseract.image_to_string(gray,config=custom_config)

   return text

def scr (o,t,w,h,name):
   # Делает скриншот по заданным координатам и сохраняет с переданным именем
   pyautogui.screenshot('c:\\Users\\GP\\'+name, region=(o,t,w,h))

scr(pocket_card_left,pocket_card_top,pocket_card_width,pocket_card_height,img_pocket_card1)
scr(pocket_card_right,pocket_card_top,pocket_card_width,pocket_card_height,img_pocket_card2)
pocket_card1 = read_card(img_increase(img_pocket_card1,5))
pocket_card2 = read_card(img_increase(img_pocket_card2,5))
print(pocket_card1,pocket_card2)
```

Comment: Качественное распознавание текста, да ещё и часто - это вряд ли простая задача. Возможно, вы вообще решаете не ту задачу, в чём смысл этого всего, задача то у вас какая?

Comment: Как я уже сказал в описании, это распознавание для покера, я пишу программу-помощник для покера. И так как там динамично всё и нужно считывать все дейсвтия со стола, то нужно быстрое исполнение, 2-4 секунды слишком долго.